# Sitecore query, Is it possible to calculate sum of a Integer field

Tags: c#, sitecore

I would like to know if its possible to do mathematical operation (e.g. Sum ) in sitecore fast query or any other way.

I have 100s of items with field 'Money spend' data type 'Integer'. I want to know the fast way to calculate the sum of this field for a specific person/user.

Here is what I am doing, I am using fast query to get the items and then calculating the sum.

```
var searchStr = "{30218229-CFA8-4BC3-9F01-01E3E6469E51}";
var query = string.Format("fast:/sitecore/content/Intranet/User/Detail/*[@Active ='1']//*[@Profile Id=\"%{0}%\"]", searchStr);
var items = Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems(query);
    //Calculate sum
var sum = items.Aggregate(0, (x, y) => x + GeneralHelper.ConvertToInt16(y["Money spend"]));
```

I want to know how I can make the sum calculation process fast?

Comment: Naw mate. You're going to need to use proper indexing technology. I suggest you look into Sitecore.ContentSearch documentation - it's enabled OOTB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to use indexes (as Mark already mentioned):

- create a custom index for your users and include your "money spend" value in it (and also the 'active' and 'profile id' as you are querying on those). Make sure the "money spend" is "stored".
- create a custom class deriving from SearchResultItem to include the "money spend" field as a property
- use the contentsearch api to query your users as you did with the fast query (index will be faster) and use your custom class that you just created to gather the results
- use Linq to calculate what you need